# Spring security RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've faced the same problem as the OP of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613865/spring-security-return-status-401-when-authenticationmanager-throws-badcredenti) question. Unfortunately I can't point my filter config to this filter.

How can I link my `customRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter` in `spring-security.xml`?

In other words: I've already done what the answer of the linked question said, but I can't go further. I have `spring-security.xml` in which there is a link to my custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-custom-filters

```
<http>
<custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myFilter" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="customRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter" class="com.mycompany.MySpecialAuthenticationFilter"/>
```