# Spring security - customizing response status according to UserDetails

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

**Intro**
I have just asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40277519/4723795) which answered might lead to a solution, however there might be a better way to do that. The security is provided by [spring-security](/questions/tagged/spring-security).

**Problem description**
I store Users in `DynamoDB`. By following a certain flow - which isn't a case here - might be awarded with a special `veryImportantUser=true` parameter. I'd like to return custom status code `202` in this case, so front-end can show to such user certain view.

**What I have:**
I have `MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler` with the following `onAuthentcationSuccess`:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    MyUserDetails userDetails = (MyUserDetails)SecurityContexHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    if (userDetails.isVIP())
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
}
```

**Problem:**
I put a *breakpoint* in that method and it gets triggered. The response status is set to `202` but in my `Postman` I receive status `200`. Can I handle it in other way then `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter`? I'd love to do that without struggling with `xml` configuration.

Comment: Are you sure you want 202? It indicates that processing has not completed

Comment: Yes. The story of the VIP isn't real. I had to censor it due to company policy. In fact, 202 matches perfectly

Comment: Censoring it for company policy sounds more like a 403 "Forbidden" than 202 "Accepted": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403